# How to update a cookie value (and not change the expire date)? javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have next code where I do:

Check if my cookie exist if it not exist then I create the cookie called value
inside else  I read the cookie again and check if value is 1, here i would like to set a new value but not change the expire date and time of this cookie only update the value

```
if( readCookie("value")==null)
{

createCookie("value",1,1);
}
else
{
if(readCookie("value")==1)
{
/*here I would like to set to cookie called value the new value to 2 */
}
else
{
alert("no es uno");
}
}

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Comment: So whats' the problem?  It looks like you are doing just what you want to do.

Comment: I have  ReadCookie, CreateCookie, and eraseCookie, now I need an UpdateCookie (but not afected the expires date assigned in creeateCookie)

Answer (score 2):

While you can't directly check the expiry date, when you set the cookie up you can store the expiry date as part of the cookie. Then whenever you want to check the expiry date, you can look at that part of the cookie. And to change the cookie without affecting the expiry date, just recreate the cookie, replacing the expiry date.

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

You can always change the expiry date of the cookie when it is being created.

Comment: Clever trick, wastes a bit of space but that's ok. Won't work if multiple parties are setting the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to `get` expiration date of setted cookie in JavaScript, you can just get the value of cookie, so, I guess, without this knowledge you cant set cookie without replacing previous value of expiration.

Comment: I want to update the value, for example You have this cookie  document.cookie="username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";  I only want to update username=not john smit; and I want to expires was not affected, I want the new value was it  document.cookie="username=no John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";  the expires was not afected

Comment: @angel We know what you want to do, you were clear in the question. It's not possible.

Comment: When you try to set cookie you replace all of its "attributes" (and expiration date too)

Comment: is not there a "trick"? for example getting with one loop the  all attributes  (by name of cookie) and after  erase and create the cookie again but previous I got the old attributes and creating I am setting only the value and setting the other attributes of old cookie

Comment: `document.cookie` - the only way to set one cookie and get all cookies(at the moment). When you get cookies you get only its values, that's all :). Do you see some other information inside `document.cookie` when you get it except of names and values of cookies??? :)