# How to change cookies value without specifying expire time/date? Javascript

Tags: javascript

It seems that I cant change the result of a cookie without add the expiration.

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + result + ";" + exp + ";path=/";
```

The code above will add the new value to current cookie. But the code below will create a new cookie with same name but a different value.

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + result;
```

Why would it crate a new cookie? and how do I fix this without having to add a new expire date?

Comment: `document.cookie` is a string. The statement `document.cookie = ...` sets that string. You need to manually parse the cookie string and change a specific substring and then set the changed string again as `document.cookie`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900269/how-to-update-a-cookie-value-and-not-change-the-expire-date-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a cookie value (and not change the expire date)? javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900269/how-to-update-a-cookie-value-and-not-change-the-expire-date-javascript)